# Laravel foreach always returning first data

Tags: php, sql, laravel

In this foreach, I use a function to pull the scores, I write the value I get from the foreach into the function.

```
foreach($surveys AS $s) {
        $surList[$s->cat][] = ["id" => $s->id, "title" => $s->title, "score" => SurveyController::getScore($s->id),"subtitle" => SurveyController::getSubtitle($s->id,SurveyController::getScore($s->id)) ];
    }
```

And in this function returns the message that corresponds to the score we got with case-when in the database

```
 function getSubtitle($id,$score){
    $surveys=DB::table("methodolgy")->where("main_survey",$id)->selectRaw("*, (CASE WHEN ".$score." BETWEEN start AND end THEN message ELSE 'bos' END) AS sonuc")->having("sonuc","!=","'bos'")->orderBy("id","ASC")->first();
    return isset($surveys->message) ? $surveys->message : "Activity Not Found";
}
```

The problem is, when I try my [query](https://prnt.sc/1tgxqci) in SQL, the result is [correct](https://prnt.sc/1tgxtpm), but when I try it on my website, it always returns the first record in my methodolgy table.
I couldn't find why it does that.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the foreach function always reads the aray and foreach data in the array it does something. For your case it is assigning data to a variable. You can create a variable like $allData and then append every data of the array to it. for example

```
$surList = [];    
foreach($surveys AS $s) {
        $oneData[$s->cat][] = ["id" => $s->id, "title" => $s->title, "score" => SurveyController::getScore($s->id),"subtitle" => SurveyController::getSubtitle($s->id,SurveyController::getScore($s->id)) ];
        $surList.=$oneData;
    }
```